# GAM not actually using categorical variables?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I am very new to GAMs, but I am trying to use `gam()` from the `mgcv` package to fit a logistic regression model using cubic splines. I'm hoping to predict `Type` based on my other varibles. The continuous variables seem to work fine in the model, but for some reason it seems to be skipping over (not actually using) my categorical (dummy) variables even after I've formatted them as factors (which I've read is a common problem).

Here's an example of my data (saved as `data1`):

| Type | precip | temp | dummy1 | dummy2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Good | 3.47 | 12.25 | 1 | 0 |
| Good | 8.64 | 11.10 | 0 | 1 |
| Bad | 10.08 | 15.67 | 0 | 0 |
| Bad | 1.34 | 14.03 | 0 | 1 |

And here's the code that I've tried:

```
data1$dummy1 <- as.factor(data1$dummy1)
data1$dummy2 <- as.factor(data1$dummy2)

require(mgcv)

modeltest <- gam(Type~ 
                s(precip)+   
                s(temp)+
                dummy1+
                dummy2,
                bs=cr,  
              data = data1,
              family = binomial,
              method = "REML")
```

It's my understanding that the dummy variables should be linear, so they don't need the `s()` that's used to smooth the continuous variables. Also, I believe the `bs=cr` is supposed to use cubic functions for the splines (although I think I might be missing information about the knots?). I think the `family=binomial` is supposed to use a logistic curve for predictions (but I'm not quite there yet) and that the `method = "REML"` is the method used to fit the smooths.

When I run all this, it looks like it works at first glance, but it doesn't provide plots for the dummy variables when I run `plot(modeltest, residuals =TRUE)` which makes me think it hasn't actually used those variables? Is this true? If so, how would I correct the model? If not, how would I get the plots for the dummy variables?

Comment: Take a look at the `by=` argument to `s()`

Comment: This fits a different smooth depending on the value of the dummy variable, right? Is there a way to just fit one smooth for each dummy variable? My actual dataset has so many different variables that I believe fitting every single factor-smooth interaction would make the model way too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `bs = 'cr'` bit *inside* each of the `s( )` terms; at the moment it is being ignored as it isn't an argument to `gam()` but is getting passed along via `...` and silently ignored.

If you run `summary(modeltest)` you'll see the parametric terms listed for the factors. To see them in the plot, you need to add `all.terms = TRUE` to also have them plotted using `termplot`.

If you want to specify where the knots should be located, then see the `knots` argument to `gam` (in `?gam`), though unless you really want to fiddle with this, *mgcv* is placing them evenly over the range of the covariate for you.